# Mostrar un botón tras pulsar otros en jquery

Tags: jquery, variables

necesito ayuda con un pequeño script que estoy haciendo.

Tengo 4 botones que al pulsarlos hacen aparecer un pequeño texto de explicación. Es para una infografía interactiva educativa.

Bien, lo que necesito es saber cómo puedo hacer que tras pulsar los 4 botones anteriores, al menos una vez cada uno, aparezca un quinto botón para hacerlo funcionar como mensaje de despedida.

Lo que tengo funcionando ahora es esto:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    
    
    $("[id*='_btn']").click(function() {
      $("[id*='exp-']").fadeOut();
      

  });
  $("#hiragana_btn").click(function() {
    
    $("#exp-hiragana").fadeIn();
     

  });
    
    $("#katakana_btn").click(function() {
      
    $("#exp-katakana").fadeIn();
        

  });
    
    $("#kanji_btn").click(function() {
      
    $("#exp-kanji").fadeIn();
    

  });
    
    $("#romaji_btn").click(function() {
      
    $("#exp-romaji").fadeIn();
        

  });
    
    // Aquí necesito el código para que cuando los 4 de arriba se hayan pulsado al menos una vez cada uno aparezca un quinto que cumpla la función que viene a continuación.
        
    $("#despedida").click(function() {
      
    $("#sayounara").fadeIn();

  });
});
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML

Comment: Has intentado     $("#exp-hiragana").show() ; ?

Comment: yo creo que lo que pudieras hacer es tener una variable por cada botón, cada que se pulse un botón la cambias a true, y en cada evento mandas validar una función donde validas si las 4 o las n están en true, muestras tu ventana.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sería hacer un array de los botones en los cuales contenga un valor booleano, por lo tanto, cada vez que se pulse un botón comprobará si todos los botones han sido pulsados y mostrará el último botón

```js
let arrayBotones = [false,false,false,false];

    /**
     * Comprobamos que si todos los botones han sido pulsados podemos mostrar el último.
     */
    function comprobarBotones() {
        let index = 0;
        for(let i=0;i<arrayBotones.length;i++) if(arrayBotones[i] == true) index++;
        
        if(index == 4) console.log("Todos los botones pulsados!");
    }

    /**
     * Actualizamos cada botón
     * @param {Integer} indexBoton 
     */
    function clickBoton(indexBoton) {

        arrayBotones[indexBoton] = true;

        //Verificamos que todos los botones hayan sido pulsados
        comprobarBotones();
    }
    
    
    $("[id*='_btn']").click(function() {

        $("[id*='exp-']").fadeOut();


    });



    $("#hiragana_btn").click(function() {
        $("#exp-hiragana").fadeIn();

        //Hacemos click al primer botón.
        clickBoton(0);

    });

    $("#katakana_btn").click(function() {
      
        $("#exp-katakana").fadeIn();

        //Hacemos click al segundo botón.
        clickBoton(1);
        

    });
    
    $("#kanji_btn").click(function() {
      
        $("#exp-kanji").fadeIn();

        //Hacemos click al tercer botón.
        clickBoton(2);

    });
    
    $("#romaji_btn").click(function() {
        
        $("#exp-romaji").fadeIn();
        //Hacemos click al cuarto botón.
        clickBoton(3);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser esta solución ya que cuando pulsa en cualquier botón muestra un alert con un texto y aparecerá después de cerrar el alert un botón de despedida detrás de cada botón. Te pongo el código que he usado para hacer comprobaciones.

```javascript
/**
 * El código es el siguiente
 */

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button:nth-child(1)").click(function(){
        alert('texto de informacion');
        $("button").after("<button>Boton despedida</button>");
    });
    $("button:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
        alert('texto de informacion');
        $("button").after("<button>Boton despedida</button>");
    });
    $("button:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
        alert('texto de informacion');
        $("button").after("<button>Boton despedida</button>");
    });
    $("button:nth-child(4)").click(function(){
        alert('texto de informacion');
        $("button").after("<button>Boton despedida</button>");
    }); 
});
```